# How to match just first word?

Tags: c#, regex, text, input, match

I know that this question seems to be banal, but I have small problem. I'm trying to match input similar to this:

```
%!: Word Word=888 Word=AAA
```

... using this regex:

```
[A-Za-z]*
```

I need just to select first word whitch contains **only** characters.
My C# code:

```
string res = Regex.Match("[A-Za-z]*", this.Content, RegexOptions.Singleline).Value;
```

Please help me. It's not working for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're basically there.

Your regex should be `@"\b[A-Za-z]+\b".`

And then, if you're wondering why you aren't getting any matches. It's because you mixed up the input and pattern parameters :)

You want:

```
string res = Regex.Match(this.Content, @"\b[A-Za-z]+\b", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value;
```

NOT:

```
string res = Regex.Match(@"\b[A-Za-z]+\b",this.Content,  RegexOptions.Singleline).Value;
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

[A-Za-z]+ watches one or more occurences of anything in the brackets. The * will match zero or more occurences.

Answer (score 1):

Another option (which may be useful if you need to pick other words too) is to match all words and pick first:

```
new Regex(@"\b[A-Za-z]+\b").Matches("%!: Word Word=888 Word=AAA")[0]
```

Comment: What if the input string is 100 megabytes? Ah, you just edited to add "(which may be useful if you need to pick other words too)." Alright. Fair enough. :)

Comment: @aquinas, yes, would be disaster... also OP's input feels like some semi-formatted string of some sort of log file - so may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Add a carrot `^` to the start of the expression to match from the start, aka only the first.